# Git merging updated master into a branch

Tags: c++, git, testing, merge

At some point, I decided to start having tests for my C++ classes. So I went to my master branch and branched from it into a new branch called "testing". I created a /tests folder with some basic tests, and added the test program names under check_PROGRAMS in my Automake.am file (I use GNU Build System, a.k.a Autotools, as my build system).

Since my project is still in very early stages, there's no stable version. Most interfaces are stil being built, so it's too early to write full tests for all interfaces, because the interfaces will change and I'll have to rewrite many tests anyway. But I have a branch in which I've developed some more-or-less stand-alone algorithms which I want to test. My GUI isn't complete, but I do want to test the algorithms before I write the GUI which uses them.

So the options I see are:
1. Merge "testing" to master, then merge "master" to the algorithm branch
2. Merge "testing" to the algorithm branch
3. Just create a /tests folder in the algorithm branch without any merging for now

Some branches have some files renamed or removed because it's such an early stage, so if I merge testing/master into the algorithm branch, I'll get a tests folder full of irrelevant tests. But the algorithm interfaces are the first part of the project to be fully ready to test and become stable and ready to use, so if I don't merge, I get a "clean" tests folder in which the only test for now is the one testing the algorithms, which are the first piece of with ready interface so I don't expect changes there, just fixing bugs I detect which testing.

What would be the best merging/not merging strategy here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. If you already did some configuration on your "testing" branch for the tests to work, then go for option 2:

   ```
   Merge "testing" to the "algorithm" branch
   ```

   That way, you don't loose time configuring everything again.

   As for the tests you call irrelevants, if they are really irrelevant, you could simply delete them before performing the merge. But tests that check if the test configuration works are not irrelevant. I don't know if this is your case.
2. The second option would be to create a new branch from "algorithm", let's call it "**algorithm2**".

   ```
   Merge "testing" into "algorithm2"
   ```

   If everything worked as you expected, then you can remove the "algorithm" branch. This would be a safe way of introducing new changes to your algorithms branch.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want your tests in a different branch? Branches in git are generally for switching between parallel versions of a project e.g. "stable" and "development". What is the purpose of switching between "the version with tests" and "the version without tests"?

What would make the most sense is to have tests in all of your branches. Then the tests in your master branch don't need to work yet since your code isn't done and you can get the tests in your algorithm branch working before the master ones do. When you eventually get the master tests working, you can merge the algorithm branch in.

Answer (score 0):

best general strategy is make main branch which holds the stable or going to be stable version. 1.0, 2.0 ..etc
Then for each test or feature you create something called feature branch.
Deleting files is not a big deal as git rm file will complete that in the merge.
always merge with the main branch (2.0) through pull requests

have fun.